# Convert not in subquery to join

Tags: mysql

I am not sure what I am missing in a query where i am trying to convert a not in subquery to join.

Here is my original query that works perfectly for me:

```
select 
  battery_id
from 
  battery_price
where 
clinic_id = 2
and battery_id not in 
(
    select battery_id
    from battery_price
    where clinic_id = 4569
) 
;
```

Here is the query that I am trying and it does not work because it does not give me any null field:

```
select leftq.battery_id as leftf, rightq.battery_id as rightf
from
    (
    select 
      battery_id
    from 
      battery_price 
    where
        clinic_id = 2
    ) as leftq
left join 
        (
            select battery_id
            from battery_price
            where clinic_id = 4569
        )  as rightq
on rightq.battery_id = leftq.battery_id
;
```

Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `battery_price` (
  `battery_price_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clinic_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `battery_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `retail_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `actual_cost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `provider_cost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `in_use` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sales_tax_id1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sales_tax_id2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sales_tax_id3` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sales_tax_id4` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sales_tax_id5` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sales_tax_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price_locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `item_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_update` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_edit_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`battery_price_id`),
  KEY `battery_id` (`battery_id`),
  KEY `battery_id_2` (`battery_id`),
  KEY `battery_id_3` (`battery_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2639 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: If you have troubles with joins you can also use a correlated `NOT EXISTS` subquery, which should perform as good as an excluding LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select
  t.battery_id
from 
  battery_price t
left outer join battery_price u
  on t.battery_id = u.battery_id
 and u.clinic_id = 4569
where t.clinic_id = 2
and u.battery_id is NULL
```

Comment: MySQL throws `Column 'battery_id' in field list is ambiguous` for this. Selecting `t.battery_id` fixes the problem.

Comment: Why distinct? There is no distinct in the original query.

Comment: Exactly., This is the classic `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern for finding right-side rows that do not have left side matches.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not quite sure why you want to select a NULL column (if you don't, just omit the second selected column after the comma), I think this query solves your problem:

```
select battery_price.battery_id as leftf, rightq.battery_id as rightf
from battery_price left join 
(
  select battery_id
  from battery_price
  where clinic_id = 4569
) as rightq
on rightq.battery_id = battery_price.battery_id
where battery_price.clinic_id = 2 and rightq.battery_id is null;
```

Comment: @AlexZen Your answer should be the accepted one, as it would be faster in most cases, I just didn't think of optimizing OP's code while fixing it :)